# How to get all identically-named attributes of all identically-named elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an xml like below and I want to know how can I output all the attributes under the same node.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Person ID="1234">
      <NAME>Louis  //</NAME>
      <SEX>M</SEX>
      <BIRT>
         <DATE>15 SEP 1980</DATE>
         <PLAC>UK</PLAC>
      </BIRT>
      <FAMS REF="F523"/>
      <FAMS REF="F524"/>
      <FAMC REF="F521"/>
   </INDI>
```

And I want to output a the FAMS and FAMC as below:
FAMS: F523, F524
FAMC: F521

Thanks,
Lawrence

Comment: [How far did you get when trying yourself?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have tried to do something like: 
        <xsl:for-each select="FAMS/node()">
         FAMS: <xsl:value-of select="@REF" />
        </xsl:for-each>

Comment: I can't test right now, but try to use just `FAMS` rather than `FAMS/node()` in your `for-each` XPath. `FAMS/node()` would select the contents nodes of `FAMS` elements.

Comment: Great - Can you either accept one of the existing answers that matches what works now, or write an answer with your final solution yourself and accept your own answer, please? (That is for future readers, so they know how the problem could be solved.)

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FAMS[1]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FAMC[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FAMS|FAMC">
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>: <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[name()=name(current())]/@REF"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@REF">
  <xsl:if test="not(position() =1)">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided (and corrected to become well-formed) XML document:**

```
<Person ID="1234">
    <NAME>Louis  //</NAME>
    <SEX>M</SEX>
    <BIRT>
        <DATE>15 SEP 1980</DATE>
        <PLAC>UK</PLAC>
    </BIRT>
    <FAMS REF="F523"/>
    <FAMS REF="F524"/>
    <FAMC REF="F521"/>
</Person>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
FAMS: F523, F524
FAMC: F521
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath to match all attributes of element `x` is `x/@*`, or for the current (context) node is `@*`.

Answer (score 0):

The path is `FAMS/@REF`:

```
<xsl:template match="Person">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FAMS/@REF"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FAMS/@REF">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('FAMS> ', .)"/>
</xsl:template>
```